# Difference between tap / delete and except in Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am facing a very curious behavior. This is Ruby 2.6.6, so a block hash variable in a loop isn't frozen. In this example, `source` is frozen.

Doing this:

```
result = source.tap { |s| s.delete(:key) }
```

Brings back a copy of the `source` without the `:key` key.

In theory, so does this:

```
result = source.except(:key)
```

and this as well:

```
result = source.dup.tap { |s| s.delete(:key) }
```

To my understanding, the above 3 syntaxes have identical outcome.

However, in tests (Ruby 2.6.6, Rails 6.0.6.1) the spec with the first syntax succeeds and the latter two fail. I don't know if it is important to state which test exactly, I am just looking for an explanation.

Any suggestion as to why would this be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are surprised that the version with `dup` leaves `source` unchanged?

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to use the result, not the source.

Comment: @spickermann I know what dup does. I am surprised that there is different outcome when using dup to get a copy -of the copy of source into result, instead of not using it and getting a copy of source into the result

Comment: _"This is Ruby 2.6.6, so a frozen hash can be modified"_ – can you elaborate? I'm not aware of _any_ Ruby version that would allow modification of frozen hashes. Trying `source = {key: 123}.freeze` and `source.delete(:key)` in Ruby 2.6.6 results in `FrozenError: can't modify frozen Hash`

Comment: @Stefan It can't sorry. I'll correct it. The change is that loop variables are now frozen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary**

Option 1 uses `Object#tap`. `Object#tap`:

> Yields self to the block, and then returns self. The primary purpose of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

This does not create a "copy" so by using `Hash#delete` you are modifying `source` in place.

Options 2 and 3 do create a shallow copy.

This means that if #1 works in your testing, while #2 and #3 do not, it is reasonable to assume you are testing `source` and not `result`.

**TL;DR**

Let's evaluate the following statement: *"Brings back a copy of the `source` without the `:key` key."*

For brevity we will use `source = {key: 10}`

Examples and Explanations:

- Example 1: `result = source.tap { |s| s.delete(:key) }`

  - *"Brings back a copy of the `source` without the `:key` key."* - FALSE. This returns `source` without the `:key` key.

```
result = source.tap { |s| s.delete(:key) }
#= > {} 
result == source 
#=> true
source
# {}
```

- Example 2: `result = source.except(:key)`

  - *"Brings back a copy of the `source` without the `:key` key."* - TRUE (in Rails > 3.0 and Ruby > 2.7)

```
result = source.except(:key)
#=> {} 
result == source 
#=> false
source
# {key: 10}
```

- Example 3: `result = source.dup.tap { |s| s.delete(:key) }`

  - *"Brings back a copy of the `source` without the `:key` key."* - TRUE

```
result = source.dup.tap { |s| s.delete(:key) }
#=> {} 
result == source 
#=> false
source
# {key: 10}
```

Comment: I like your answer, it is complete. However, 'source' is not used after the assignment to result. Result1 == Result2 == Result3 works, even with triple equality (===). But I wasn't looking for a solution, I was looking for an answer and I got it.

Comment: @RubyRacer yes all the results are equivalent. Their impact is not.